# does Star Alliance Gold Tier allow entry into Emirates and Vistara lounges

Tags: emirates, lounges, air-india, star-alliance

I am Star Alliance Gold (United MileagePlus) tier for this member. My booking (not using award miles) for an upcoming trip includes some longer waits at airports, so I was wondering if this Star Alliance Gold tier allows me into the lounges of Emirates (at DXB) and Delhi (Vistara).

Comment: What airline(s) are you flying?  If Emirates and Vistara, sorry, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, you should be able to use any “member airline lounge” when you fly a Star Alliance flight while holding the Star Alliance Gold level as you say you hold.

This means that, lounges like Plaza Premium or Al Majlis at DXB will not be allowing you in for free (you can pay to enter those) but you should be able to access any airline member lounge so your only option to access using your Star Alliance Gold membership would be the Lufthansa lounge (they founded Star Alliance after all).

Similarly in Delhi international airport: only terminal 3 has international flights and there only the Air India lounge (part of Star Alliance) should allow you in with your Star Alliance Gold membership.

Generally speaking though, if you fly on business class or first class then that’s a different story because you would then be able to just go to the lounge reserved for business class ticket holders or the one for first class ticket holders depending on your ticket.

Hope this answers your question and have a safe trip wherever you go!

[Reference link for Star Alliance Gold lounge access](https://www.staralliance.com/en/lounge-access-policy#:%7E:text=bring%20any%20guests.-,Star%20Alliance%20Gold%20Customers,domestic%20flight%20with%20United.,-Paid%20Lounge%20Membership)

[DXB Lufthansa lounge details, airport website](https://www.dubaiairports.ae/while-youre-here/relax-refresh/lounges/lounge-details/lufthansa-lounge#)

[Delhi Air India lounge details, independent review](https://www.loungebuddy.com/DEL/air-india-maharajah-lounge-terminal-3-international-kEiF2Ir7P5)

[DXB Lufthansa business class lounge / Gold members, independent review](https://www.loungebuddy.com/DXB/lufthansa-business-lounge-terminal-1-concourse-d-FK9ZEBpuK7?source=homepage)

[Lufthansa Senator level lounge, independent review](https://www.loungebuddy.com/DXB/lufthansa-senator-lounge-terminal-1-concourse-d-dTFJy1oQ7M?source=homepage)

Comment: If the OP has gold membership with Stat Alliance then the OP will be able to go into any “member airline” lounge even when not travelling with them . The case you mention is the classic case of having a ticket in business or first for a given airline then you get access to that airline lounge regardless of having a certain level of any membership. It’s two different things, I have explained this in my answer with links to back it up

Comment: No, you need a same-day Star Alliance flight ticket. From your own link: *'If the following conditions are met: You present your boarding pass of a Star Alliance member airline operated flight which departs at the same day as your visit or latest by 05:00 AM the next morning."*

Comment: United notoriously doesn't allow its own gold members into its lounges for US domestic flights. Just saying....